# Check scrapy result in bash

Tags: python, bash, scrapy

I have multiple spiders that i run in a bash script like so:

```
pipenv run scrapy runspider -o output-a.json a.py
pipenv run scrapy runspider -o output-b.json b.py
```

Since they should run for a long time I'd like to have a simple way of monitoring their success rate; my plan was to ping https://healtchecks.io when both scrapers run successfully (i.e. they don't have any error messages). I've sprinkled some `assert` statements over the code to be reasonably confident about this.

```
pipenv run scrapy runspider -o output-a.json a.py
result_a=$?
pipenv run scrapy runspider -o output-b.json b.py
result_b=$?

if [ $result_a -eq 0 && $result_b -eq 0]; then
    curl $url
fi
```

My problem is that each `scrapy runspider` command always returns `0` no matter what. That means I can't really check whether they have been succesful.

Is there a way to influence this behavior? Some command line flag I haven't found? If not, how would I run the two spiders from a python script and save their output to a defined location? I found [this link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) but it doesn't mention how to handle the returned items.

Comment: Yes, just configure [logging](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)

Comment: I believe the correct syntax there would be `[ $result_a -eq 0 -a $result_b -eq 0 ]` or you could do `[ $result_a -eq 0 ] && [ $result_b -eq 0 ]` which is more accepted.  I am going to assume this is a typo since this would generate erros the way it is typed in the question.  Either way, why not send a non-zero return code from your python script on error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually solved this was assigning the log output to a variable and `grep`ping it for `ERROR: Spider error processing`. Scrapy has the very nice behavior of not failing unnecessarily early; if I exited the python script myself I would have lost that. This way I could just run one scraper after another and handle the errors in the end, so I could still collect as much as possible while being notified in the case that something doesn't run 100% smoothly.